# How do you save the level-ups to Skylanders Giants figurines?

Tags: skylanders-giants

Started playing Skylanders Giants last night and leveled up to Level 3 on Tree Rex.  However, when we switched to 1 player on the same story line instead of 2, and went back to the first world/level to get items we had missed, it dropped back to Level 1 instead of Level 3.  Could have been because we switched out characters as well.  Is there a way to hard save to the figurine what you have done with it? Haven't been able to find the controls to do so.  It's a Wii Portal, if that makes a difference. Thanks!

Comment: We are having the same problem and so are many other players according to blogs. Someone said to log in prior to starting the game whatever that means.

Answer (score 1):

You basically just have to leave it on the portal long enough for it to save, so I think it's just that you turned your system off withuot giving it a chance to save or it glitched. eitherv way you won't be able to get your level-ups back, unless you re-earn them

Answer (score 0):

What I do is go to a random level and then get out of it.

When I first play that happen to me

So I started doing that so my tree Rex is level 15